# how can I chop strings in a consecutive region with various moving window

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(sname = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Carrot", "Melon"
), class = "factor"), sence = structure(1:2, .Label = c("RSNSNASSAVSTSCVSNRAMKGTTHYDTS", 
"TGMRHGGMVSVCMCVVDDNRRRHYNGAYDDHHRGGVCTS"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Lets look at the first row

```
Melon RSNSNASSAVSTSCVSNRAMKGTTHYDTS
```

I want to be able to chop the strings into different windows as well as moving in different pattern. for example lets say moving 1 letter at the time and windows of 10. so The first output will be like this

```
RSNSNASSAV
```

So this one is letter 1 ,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

The second one will be moving 1 letter forward and then chop for 10 letters

```
SNSNASSAVS
```

so this is letter 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
it goes until the end.

a requested output is like the following

```
output<- structure(list(position = structure(c(33L, 1L, 12L, 23L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 13L, 32L, 1L, 12L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L), .Label = c("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10", 
"10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19", "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20", 
"12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22", 
"14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23", "15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24", 
"16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25", "17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26", 
"18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27", "19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28", 
"2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11", "20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29", "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30", 
"22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31", "23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32", 
"24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33", "25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34", 
"26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35", "27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36", 
"28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37", "29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38", 
"3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12", "30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39", "31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40", 
"4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13", "5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14", "6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15", 
"7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16", "8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17", 
"9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18", "Carrot", "Melon"), class = "factor"), 
    name = structure(c(20L, 32L, 37L, 26L, 35L, 35L, 2L, 38L, 
    33L, 3L, 46L, 39L, 42L, 34L, 7L, 45L, 36L, 24L, 27L, 1L, 
    21L, 5L, 41L, 15L, 22L, 28L, 17L, 14L, 16L, 23L, 47L, 40L, 
    43L, 6L, 19L, 8L, 19L, 8L, 48L, 44L, 10L, 12L, 25L, 31L, 
    30L, 29L, 18L, 50L, 13L, 4L, 49L, 9L, 11L), .Label = c("AMKGTTHYDT", 
    "ASSAVSTSCV", "AVSTSCVSNR", "AYDDHHRGGV", "Carrot", "CMCVVDDNRR", 
    "CVSNRAMKGT", "CVVDDNRRRH", "DDHHRGGVCT", "DDNRRRHYNG", "DHHRGGVCTS", 
    "DNRRRHYNGA", "GAYDDHHRGG", "GGMVSVCMCV", "GMRHGGMVSV", "GMVSVCMCVV", 
    "HGGMVSVCMC", "HYNGAYDDHH", "MCVVDDNRRR", "Melon", "MKGTTHYDTS", 
    "MRHGGMVSVC", "MVSVCMCVVD", "NRAMKGTTHY", "NRRRHYNGAY", "NSNASSAVST", 
    "RAMKGTTHYD", "RHGGMVSVCM", "RHYNGAYDDH", "RRHYNGAYDD", "RRRHYNGAYD", 
    "RSNSNASSAV", "SAVSTSCVSN", "SCVSNRAMKG", "SNASSAVSTS", "SNRAMKGTTH", 
    "SNSNASSAVS", "SSAVSTSCVS", "STSCVSNRAM", "SVCMCVVDDN", "TGMRHGGMVS", 
    "TSCVSNRAMK", "VCMCVVDDNR", "VDDNRRRHYN", "VSNRAMKGTT", "VSTSCVSNRA", 
    "VSVCMCVVDD", "VVDDNRRRHY", "YDDHHRGGVC", "YNGAYDDHHR"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L))
```

Split with 2

```
RSNSNASSAV
NSNASSAVST
NASSAVSTSC
SSAVSTSCVS
AVSTSCVSNR
STSCVSNRAM
SCVSNRAMKG
VSNRAMKGTT
NRAMKGTTHY
AMKGTTHYDT
KGTTHYDTS
```

Comment: I think the second row should be `39` instead of 40 as `nchar` is 39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert the `factor` columns to `character`, then `transmute` to createa `tibble` of 'position', 'name' by looping over the rows with `map`, create `substring`s based on the the split width 'n' and the number of character (`nchar`) of 'sence', concatenate the 'sname' as the `first` element and `unnest` the `list` output to create a two column dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
f1 <- function(dat, n, mv = 1) {

 dat %>% 
    mutate_all(as.character) %>%
    transmute(out = map2(sence, sname, ~ {
        i1 <- seq_len(nchar(.x) - (n -1))
        i11 <- seq(i1[1], i1[length(i1)], by = mv)

        i2 <- n:nchar(.x) 
        i22 <- seq(i2[1], i2[length(i2)], by = mv) 

        tibble(position = c(.y, map2_chr(i11, i22,  ~ 
                        str_c(seq(.x, .y), collapse=","))),
                name = c(.y, substring(.x, i11, i22)))

               })) %>%
                unnest

   }
```

-testing
- moving window - 1

```
f1(df, n = 10, mv = 1)
#                        position       name
#1                          Melon      Melon
#2           1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 RSNSNASSAV
#3          2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 SNSNASSAVS
#4         3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 NSNASSAVST
#5        4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 SNASSAVSTS
#6       5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 NASSAVSTSC
#7      6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 ASSAVSTSCV
#8     7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 SSAVSTSCVS
#9    8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 SAVSTSCVSN
#10  9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 AVSTSCVSNR
#11 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 VSTSCVSNRA
#12 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 STSCVSNRAM
#13 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 TSCVSNRAMK
#14 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 SCVSNRAMKG
#15 14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 CVSNRAMKGT
#16 15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 VSNRAMKGTT
#17 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25 SNRAMKGTTH
#18 17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26 NRAMKGTTHY
#19 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27 RAMKGTTHYD
#20 19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28 AMKGTTHYDT
#21 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 MKGTTHYDTS
#22                        Carrot     Carrot
#23          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 TGMRHGGMVS
#24         2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 GMRHGGMVSV
#25        3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 MRHGGMVSVC
#26       4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 RHGGMVSVCM
#27      5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 HGGMVSVCMC
#28     6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 GGMVSVCMCV
#29    7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 GMVSVCMCVV
#30   8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 MVSVCMCVVD
#31  9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 VSVCMCVVDD
#32 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 SVCMCVVDDN
#33 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 VCMCVVDDNR
#34 12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 CMCVVDDNRR
#35 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 MCVVDDNRRR
#36 14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 CVVDDNRRRH
#37 15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 VVDDNRRRHY
#38 16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25 VDDNRRRHYN
#39 17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26 DDNRRRHYNG
#40 18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27 DNRRRHYNGA
#41 19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28 NRRRHYNGAY
#42 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 RRRHYNGAYD
#43 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30 RRHYNGAYDD
#44 22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31 RHYNGAYDDH
#45 23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 HYNGAYDDHH
#46 24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33 YNGAYDDHHR
#47 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34 NGAYDDHHRG
#48 26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35 GAYDDHHRGG
#49 27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36 AYDDHHRGGV
#50 28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37 YDDHHRGGVC
#51 29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38 DDHHRGGVCT
#52 30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39 DHHRGGVCTS
```

-moving window - 2

```
f1(df, n = 10, mv = 2) %>%
            head
#                      position       name
#1                        Melon      Melon
#2         1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 RSNSNASSAV
#3       3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 NSNASSAVST
#4     5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 NASSAVSTSC
#5   7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 SSAVSTSCVS
#6 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 AVSTSCVSNR
```

-moving window - 3

```
f1(df, n = 10, mv = 3) %>% 
         head
#                       position       name
#1                         Melon      Melon
#2          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 RSNSNASSAV
#3       4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 SNASSAVSTS
#4    7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 SSAVSTSCVS
#5 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 VSTSCVSNRA
#6 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 SCVSNRAMKG
```

-moving window - 4

```
f1(df, n = 10, mv = 4) %>% 
          head
#                       position       name
#1                         Melon      Melon
#2          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 RSNSNASSAV
#3      5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 NASSAVSTSC
#4  9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 AVSTSCVSNR
#5 13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 SCVSNRAMKG
#6 17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26 NRAMKGTTHY
```

Comment: what if the moving goes to 2 , or 3 or 4 , is there a possibility to set that as a variable too ?

Comment: @Learner Sorry, didn't get your question

Comment: now the windows is moving 1 letter at the time, what if it moves 2 letter at the time or 3 letters at the time. You know what I mean?

Comment: @Learner `substring/substr` have only `start/stop - first/last` option.  If we need that option.  then, have to create the index with `seq`

Comment: I liked your answer already but that is very important for me to be able to move the window with a parameter I set not only one

Comment: @Learner  For `"RSNSNASSAVSTSCVSNRAMKGTTHYDTS"`, can you show the splits for moving = 2.  Is it like `"RNNSAS.."`

Comment: I showed it above in my question, can you see it ? just for example we set the n to 10 (so the window is 10 letter) then we set the m to 2, meaning 2 letter moves each time forward.

Answer (score 1):

```
library('tidyverse')
# use this function to make the blocks:
make_substrings = function(string, len, label){

  # set up the indices
  str_len = nchar(string)
  indices1 = 1:(str_len-len+1)
  indices2 = (len:str_len)
  # create the list of indices
  position = map2_chr(indices1, indices2, .f = function(x, y){paste(x:y, collapse = ', ')})
  # take substrings
  name = map2_chr(indices1, indices2, .f = substr, x = string)
  # add yoru food labels
  header = tibble(position = label,
                  name = label)
  header %>% 
    bind_rows(tibble(position,
                     name))
}

# your version had factors
df = df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character)
# iterate over all the rows of df:
output = Map(f = make_substrings, string = df$sence, len = 10, label = df$sname) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

Comment: thanks this is only moving 1 letter at the time, what if I want to move 2 letter at the time or more letter at the time? is it possible to amend your solution ? I liked you answer already

Comment: @Learner, yeah I think that should be pretty easy to change. You'll want to change the indices and add another argument to the function. Look what happens to sequences when you multiply the whole thing by a constant: `(1:5)*3`